# Why are static private variables in JavaScript static?

Tags: javascript

I am reading Nicholas C. Zakas's JavaScript for Web Developers Third Edition (old, I know), and I am having trouble understanding why static private variables/functions are static in the first place. I understand that if I declared a constructor with private variables/functions, all of its instances would have their own private variables/functions, like in one of Zakas's examples:

```
function MyObject(){

    //private variables and functions 
    var privateVariable = 10;

    function privateFunction(){ 
        return false;
    }

    //privileged methods 
    this.publicMethod = function (){
        privateVariable++;
        return privateFunction(); 
    };
}
```

So how would putting private variables/functions in private scopes make the variables static? Is it just because they're enclosed in a private scope, or is there something I'm overlooking? Here's one of Zakas's examples on static private variables:

```
(function(){

   //private variables and functions 
   var privateVariable = 10;

   function privateFunction(){ 
      return false;
   }

   //constructor
   MyObject = function(){ 
   };

   //public and privileged methods
   MyObject.prototype.publicMethod = function(){ 
      privateVariable++;
      return privateFunction();
   }; 
})();
```

Comment: I think your question is rhetorical. why static variable is static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, every time you call `MyObject` a new local variable `privateVariable` is created.

In your second example, `privateVariable` is part of `function(){ ... }`, which is only called once, so only one variable is ever created. This one variable is used by `MyObject.prototype.publicMethod`, which is then shared by all objects created through `MyObject`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So it's because the private members in the second example are not actually in the constructor (and that's why they only get called once)?